# How to let a reader know that the meaning of a symbol ($N$) depends upon context (as a vector dimension or as a Noise variable)

Tags: education

There is a **conflict** of use for **one** mathematical **symbol** in my technical document that is defining two different quantities.

Due to **time constraint** I can not edit the document now. What are the possible ways to let the reader of my document know that depending on the context that *symbol* be understood accordingly.

I have a List of Symbols in my document too. Is it O.K to mention this conflict there? Or any other recommendations please.

Comment: What symbol are you using, and what are its two uses?

Comment: Are you sure you can't just put a subscript or something to indicate two different variables?

Comment: symbol is $N$. It is used to represent both dimension of vector and as a Noise variable.

Defining with subscript is a great idea but for noise variable scripting is used BUT it is also used to define the noise vector without subscript. 

Whereas to define the dimension of a vector there is no subscription in my document.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would suggest using d as the dimension of the vector as it's very frequently used in theory books and shouldn't "shock" the Physics student/professor (i guees your target?) reading ur article.
Moreover in any books i read there usually is a "legenda" at the end describing all symbol's used meaning (at least in Math's ones)
I hope it helps! :)